# Why $R/AB$ is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

> Why $R/AB$ is cyclic when $A,B$ are ideals of $R$?

I know a cyclic module is a module that can be written as $Rm$ and $Rm$ is isomorphic to $R/Ann(m)$. However, I can't see why the module is cyclic, unless AB is an annihilator of something. Can someone explain to me please?

Answer (score 0):

A cyclic module is a module, that is generated by one element. For sure $R/AB$ is generated by the class of $1$.

$AB$ is precisely the annihilator of $\overline 1 = 1+AB \in R/AB$.

Comment: if $R/AB$ is generated by 1 then doesn't that mean that $R/AB =R$?? I don't quite understand you. If your argument works, then can I say that $R/I$ is cyclic for any I since I is the annihilator of 1 + I? so all quotient module is cyclic?

Comment: $R$ is freely generated by $1$. $R/I$ is generated by $1$, but not torsion free, since $Ann(1+I)=I$. So yes, any module $R/I$ is cyclic and any cyclic module is of the form $R/I$ (with $I$ being the annihilator of the generator). You already know that result from groups: The cyclic groups are exactly the groups $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, with $n=0$ yielding the free cyclic group $\mathbb Z$. This is just the special case $R=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Is there any situation where R/I is not cyclic or is it always true that R/I is always cyclic? This only works when R contains 1 right?

Comment: You should read the 2nd sentence of my previous comment again. It is always cyclic.

Comment: yup but it says R generated by 1. So if R does not contain 1, this argument doesn't work right?

Comment: Well if $R$ does not contain $1$. then even $R$ might not be a cyclic $R$-module. I assumed this without further saying.